What are the primitive solutions to $x^3+2y^3=z^4$?
The question is to list all primitive solutions (that is, ones with $\text{gcd}(x,y,z)=1$) to the eqiuation
$$
x^3+2y^3=z^4.
$$
In particular, are there any primitive solutions except of
$$
(x,y,z)=(1,0,\pm 1), (-1,1,\pm 1) \quad \text{and} \quad (-237,203,\pm 43) \quad ?
$$
Motivation: according to our survey https://arxiv.org/abs/2412.11933 of generalized Fermat equations
$$
a x^p + b y^q = c z^r
$$
the equation in the title is the simplest-looking one (in terms of degrees and coefficients) that remains open.
A possible approach is to look at parametrized solutions to $x^3+2y^3=t^2$ from Cohen's book "Number Theory: Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools" (Section 14.3.3) and try to find solutions with $t$ being a perfect square. This leads to determining rational points on genus $2$ curves
$$
U^2=S^6+40S^3-32
$$
$$
U^2=32T^6-40T^3-1
$$
$$
U^2=9S^6+18S^5+45S^4+60S^3+15S^2-6S-5
$$
$$
U^2=5T^6+6T^5-15T^4-60T^3-45T^2-18T-9
$$
$$
U^2=17S^6+30S^5-15S^4+20S^3+15S^2+6S-1
$$
$$
U^2=T^6-6T^5-15T^4-20T^3+15T^2-30T-17.
$$
The first curve has rank of Jacobian $1$ and can be solved by Chabauty command in magma, but some other curves either have rank $2$ or do not have an obvious rational point needed for this command.
